# Wordpress quizzes - payments and subscriptions

Tags: wordpress, online-payment, login

I created a website using WordPress(and using HostGator as the web host) for Math practice quizzes. I am using mTouch quiz which seems to do the job for me for now.

Recommendations needed for the following requirements:

1. Users can login and attempt practice quizzes only if they have paid
2. Monthly subscription with automatic renewals
3. If paying for multiple months at a time, allow for discounts
4. Do not allow users to take quizzes if they have not paid for a month
5. As I have a large number of quizzes with a lot of questions, I still have to figure out a method of Importing/Exporting questions from the mTouch quiz database

Which of the above items are available as plug-ins? Is there a way to link the quizzes to payments or do I need programming help for it. Also, in general, is it safe to accept payments using a WordPress plugin?

Any help is appreciated. I am planning on hiring a programmer, but needed to get an idea of the scope of the work involved. Thanks.